# Oracle JDBC Custom Collection Type and SQLOutput writeString

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle, jdbc

I created a type in Oracle DB:

```
 create or replace TYPE client_type AS OBJECT
  ( 
  NMB NUMBER(7,0), 
  TITLE VARCHAR2(30),
  );
```

After that I created a corresponding class in Java;

```
public class Client implements SQLData {

    private int nmb;  
    private String title;

    public int getNmb() {
        return ncst;
    }
    public void setNmb(int nmb) {
        this.nmb = nmb;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return "CLIENT_TYPE";
    }
    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
         setNmb(stream.readInt());
         setTitle(stream.readString());
    }
    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeInt(getNmb());
        stream.writeString(getTitle());
    }
}
```

Then I call a procedure to insert new data:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("P_INSERTCLIENT");
jdbcCall.declareParameters(new SqlParameter("P_CLIENT", OracleTypes.STRUCT, "CLIENT_TYPE"));
Map in = Collections.singletonMap("P_CLIENT", customer);                    
jdbcCall.execute(in);
```

NMB gets inserted in table and TITLE value is set to null... 
I tried to change my client_type, added a DATE and it also gets inserted correctly.

What am I doing wrong with string -> varchar fields?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this one.  I created your type and your class, added a stored procedure and wrote a main class to run it all, and the data went in as I expected.  So the error can only be in code or configuration you've chosen not to share with us.  What JARs are you using (including versions)?  What is the definition of your stored procedure `P_INSERTCLIENT`?

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I'm using this dependencies:
                
`<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
   <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: This is my procedure:
`create or replace PROCEDURE P_INSERTCLIENT (P_CLIENT IN CLIENT_TYPE)
AS
BEGIN
  Insert into CLIENT (NMB, TITLE) 
  VALUES (
    p_client.NMB,
    p_client.TITLE
    );
  COMMIT;
END;`

Comment: I forgot to say, I m using Spring Boot 1.3.2

Comment: If you have extra information to add, please edit your question and include it there.  Please don't post code in comments as it's difficult to read.   Having said that, I still couldn't reproduce the problem even with version 10.2.0.4 of the Oracle JDBC driver.  I'm afraid I'm out of ideas, unless you've got something silly like a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that is wiping out the value.  Sorry.

Comment: OK, I will follow your instructions in future. I discovered that, when I change my VARCHAR2 type in DB to NVARCHAR2 (in table definition and in type definition) everything works fine. So it must be something connected with charset. Unfortunately I'm not an admin of that particular DB so I cant do nothing about it...